# Facts cache content not accessible in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I've successfully enabled fact caching for Ansible and I can verify the content by opening the json files produced to the cache directory, however, when I run a task with playbook level gather_facts set to off, and I try something simple like

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: should print cached facts..
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: ansible_facts
```

The value shows as undefined. I've also tried printing out `hostvars` to see if they were rolled up elsewhere. And I've got nothing.

How do I actually refer to the variables stored in the facts cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *when I run a task with playbook level `gather_facts` set to `off`*

According [Cache plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html)

> *The default cache plugin is the memory plugin, which only caches the data for the current execution of Ansible. Other plugins with persistent storage are available to allow caching the data across runs.*

This means

> *Fact caching is always enabled. However, only one fact cache plugin can be active at a time*

therefore, if you set `gather_facts: false` you will lose access to the within the files stored facts.

[Enabling fact caching plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-fact-cache-plugins) will give you the possibility to configure the plugin, the format, as well the time after which in local files cached facts are notlonger used and re-read again from the Remote Node.

```
cat ansible.cfg
```

```ini
fact_caching            = yaml
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible/facts_cache
fact_caching_timeout    = 129600 # in seconds
```

You only need to adjust the time how long you like to use the cached values before they will become remotely gathered again.

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html)
- [`CACHE_PLUGIN_TIMEOUT`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#cache-plugin-timeout) the default value is `86400` seconds, one day

Regarding

> *What a persistent cache is useful for if one still has to go through the entire generation procedure every time in order to access that cache.*

If one is `gathering_facts`, the module `setup` is going to make a connection to a Remote Node via SSH in order to collect the information which it is configured to do for.

If `fact_cache` is enabled the information will additionally to "in memory" be stored "in file" locally on Control Node.

At the next run there might be no need to collect the information again remotely resulting into no remote connection necessary, no remote collection necessary, faster execution time, less resource consumption. If the requested information is already locally available the `setup` module can just read  the local file and transfer it into memory for further processing on the Control Node.

**Further Q&A** to get familiar with the topic `gather_facts`

- [How Ansible sets variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043335/6771046)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71060833/6771046)

Comment: In my case I have fact_caching assigned as 'jsonfile' - is that not altering the use of the memory plugin you described (meaning it's caching as a json file not in memory)?  Meaning, if I have 'gather_facts' set to off - it should only mean that the setup module isn't called but the cache should still be available right?

Comment: Regarding "_if I have `gather_facts` set to `off` - it should only mean that the setup module isn't called but the cache should still be available right?_" unfortunately not. If you do not gather facts, it is not gathering facts at all, even not the facts which are cached in file.

Comment: Hmm if that's the case, what is the point of the cache to begin with.  Intuitively I thought to make a playbook to cache all facts then leverage them elsewhere.  I'm not asking sarcastically, rather genuinely about what a persistent cache is useful for if one still has to go through the entire generation procedure every time in order to access that cache.  Ty in advance for your insight!

Comment: I've provided some more information about how the processing is working.

Comment: Aha, I see now!  So it's still 'on' but the setup module refers to the cache location in the process of assessing whether or not to actually perform a connection.  That's the bit that I think puts this into a great answer.  Tysm U880D for this hard work!